exec format error running compiled 64 bit arm assembly
I downloaded a picoCTF reverse engineering challenge file. The specific challenge was "ARMssembly 1". I was unable to run it after compiling.
I tried compiling it in Kali linux virtual box with the following command aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc chall_1.S -o chall -static
I get the error zsh: exec format error: ./chall as seen in the image.
is the file not executible or is there something else missing?
I am not running an arm processor
Problem Image

The file is not executable by your CPU. You can use an emulator like qemu-arm64 to run it.
